# O que deve ser retornado na função WndProc em C++?

Tags: c++, windows, estilo-de-codificação

Olá. Veja o código abaixo:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (message == WM_CREATE) {
        return(?);
    } else if (message == WM_COMMAND) {
        return(?);
    } else if (message == WM_CLOSE) {
        return(?);
    } else if (message == WM_DESTROY) {
        return(?);
    } else {
        return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));
    }
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber o que deve ser retornado nessa função caso ela seja processada corretamente e o que deve ser retornado se ocorrer um erro no processamento.
Também gostaria de saber, se não for pedir demais, se o código **return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));** está colocado no lugar certo.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No geral, esta função costuma utilizar o switch para verificar o evento da mensagem, mas o que você fez é equivalente. Em relação ao que deve ser retornado, quando tudo ocorre bem mas o evento não esta nas condições do switch (ou nesse caso dos "if"s), ele retorna "DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam)" no default apenas devolvendo a mensagem, ou retorna 0 no final da função após ser aceitado em um case e ter passado pelo break, ao retornar 0 você simplesmente esta retornando nada, como se o evento já tivesse sido resolvido.

Na realidade não conheço retorno dessa função para informar erro e nem sei se existe, mas geralmente, ao ocorrer um erro grave, ou o programa para de funcionar, ou você mostra uma MessageBox informando o erro e devolve mensagem no loop pedindo para fechar o programa, geralmente isso é feito usando o "PostQuitMessage(0);" que basicamente devolve a mensagem WM_CLOSE para o loop, basicamente é como fazer "return SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);".

Basicamento para não repetir varios returns você pode coloca-lo no final da função pois sempre que ele for bem sucedido ele vai retornar 0, ficaria assim:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
if (message == WM_CREATE) {
    // Ações durante o carregamento
} else if (message == WM_COMMAND) {
    // Ações ao clicar em algo
} else if (message == WM_CLOSE) {
    // Ações ao fechar a janela
} else if (message == WM_DESTROY) {
    PostQuitMessage(0); // MSG para fechar o programa, manda a mensagem WM_CLOSE
} else {
    return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam)); // Devolve a mensagem
}
return 0;  // Se o evento foi resolvido retorna 0
}
```

Sim, o "return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));" esta colocado no local certo, pois este é chamado sempre que nenhuma das condições foram aceitas, ou seja, ele é o ultimo caso por isso fica no bloco default do switch, mas ao passar por um evento retorna se 0 no final da função para informar que o evento já foi resolvido.

Espero ter ajudado